# AX / Axapta: Retrieve Custom fields via SQL

Tags: sql, axapta, business-connector

I'm creating a rather "dirty" business connector of my own here, and I'm having trouble finding those "custom fields" that have been created.

They show up in AX - but in the SQL-database, they are not mentioned at all... I have a hunch that all custom fields are stored somewhere else in the database, so that the original state of the tables does not get alterd - but where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for bringing up a dead corpse, but I found out what was going on:

The company I did this project for got two SQL-server, one is SRVSQL, and another one named SQLSRV ;) Hehe!

So all the custom fields were stored in tables in SRVSQL, while I was connected to SQLSRV ;)

(Blame the network admin ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such fields in Dyamics Ax, but some fields can have different name in SQL server, than in Axbecause field ids are added to end of field name in case of long field name. There is an SQLDictionary table to associate names in Ax and names in SQL